# uszipcode package in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using SearchEngine in uszipcode in Python. I create a for loop to go through my list of postal code and return the two letter code of approximate state. How can I get a null value for the state if the postal code is nonexistent (such as of other countries)?

```py
# list of postal code: 
postal = ['68847','32204','40112', '28304','75751']

# my for loop to get state: 
state = []
for i in range (0, len(df_copy)):
    x = sr.by_zipcode(postal_list[i]).state
    state.append(x)

# expected return:
# state = [NE,FL,null,NC,TX] 
# since 40112 is a zip code of Indonesia.
```

Comment: What does `sr` represent?